# google analytics for iOS - can it track a class of NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, nsobject

I wanted to figure out if `Google analytics` can track a class of `NSObject`. I'm using it on `UIViewControllers`, and it's great, but I didn't find any example for `NSObject`. Should it work? and if so, how?

Comment: track what aspect exactly? User interaction? Class instantiation?

Comment: track class methods that are executed.

Comment: A good option would be [Custom Metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/customdimsmets#considerations-mets)